# How create button to refresh pivot table

Tags: excel, vba, pivot

I would like create some button which will be refresh my pivot table after data changes. But my code remove all date and left empty template. This is my code. How i can resolve this

```
Sub RefreshAllPivots()

Dim pc as PivotCache
For each pc in thisWorkbook.PivotCaches

Pc.resfresh
Next pc
End sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it.

```
ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll
```

Or, loop through each one.

```
Dim Sheet as WorkSheet, Pivot as PivotTable
For Each Sheet in ThisWorkbook.WorkSheets
    For Each Pivot in Sheet.PivotTables
        Pivot.RefreshTable
        Pivot.Update
    Next
Next
```